# Are there any words in English meaning "goodbye forever"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm not a native speaker. I want to know if there is any word that you use to express that yourself and the listener will not have a chance to see each other again, or that it is incredibly unlikely you ever will. Such as when they are going abroad or dying.

Comment: This is what bilingual dictionaries are there for. Take the word in your language, look up the translation in a dictionary of your choice. Thank you.

Comment: So should this be closed as GR or moved to ELL?

Comment: @mplungjan general reference here, and general reference on ELL.

Comment: I don't think that the actual nuance would be dealt with too well (if at all) in general works of reference. 'Farewell' has a ring of finality about it (and a hint of antiquity); 'Goodbye forever' itself is extremely poetic but _could_ be used. Many people expect to see each other electronically if one party is merely emigrating; many people expect to see each other in another place (state?) if they believe in an afterlife.

Comment: "See you on the other side."

Comment: I'd have thought 'See you in a day or two' was more appropriate in your case.

Comment: *Adieu* is explicitly opposed to *Au revoir*, in English as well as French, as in the old song '...kind friends adieu, adieu/ I can no longer stay with you.'

Comment: Reminds me of the end of the Pete and Dud sketch: "Goodbye Sah! – Or is it au revoir?" "No, Perkins."

Comment: Well this is disappointing. Finding a polite word or phrase that clearly connotes permanent goodbye (with no alternate interpretation as temporary) is non-trivial.